# Unordered list doesn't span whole of div

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm have a `ul` in a div (`left-nav-bar`). I'm trying to get the `ul` to span across the whole div when the user hovers over it, but there is whitespace generated before each `li` and I'm not sure why.

[image]

I've tried:

```
.nav-container ul{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Which allows the ul to extend beyond the text, but doesn't address the whitespace.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ytynqhmj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ul` elements have a left padding by default.

Add `padding: 0;` or `padding-left: 0;` to `.nav-container ul` to avoid this

https://jsfiddle.net/ejzL9zo9/

Answer (score 1):

By default `ul` element take `padding-left: 60px;` just update it with 0px to resolve this issue. Check updated snippet below..

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
}

body {
    background-color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 .05rem .1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    display: block;
}


/** CONTAINER DIVS **/

.site-wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.site-wrapper-inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow: auto;
}

.logo-holder {
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.logo-holder h3 {
    line-height: 150px;
}

.nav-container {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
}

.nav-container a {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #333;
}

.nav-container ul {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
}

.nav-container ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav-container li:hover {
    background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="site-wrapper">
    <div class="site-wrapper-inner">
        <div class="nav-container">
            <div class="logo-holder">
                <h3>Logo</h3></div>
            <nav class="nav left-nav-bar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="nav-link active" href="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link" href="">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link" href="">Store</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Just remove default left padding for `ul` like this:**

```
.nav-container ul{
  padding-left:0;<----Added
  //more code....
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ytynqhmj/1/)